# Why does this Matrix not converge with the Power Method?

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume a $Page-Rank$ $\textit{Markov}$ Matrix:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3}\\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

My lecturer told me, that the convergence rate of the `Power Method` is defined by $\frac{|\lambda_2|}{|\lambda_1|}$ (dividing the absolute value of the second largest `Eigenvalue` by the largest `Eigenvalue`) - but $\textbf{only}$ if $\lambda_1$ is real and if $\lambda_1$ has `algebraic multiplicity` of `1`!

`numpy` said, $M$ has these Eigenvalues:

$
\lambda_1 = 1 + 0i\\
\lambda_2 = -0.49999999999999967 + 0.866025403784438i\\
\lambda_3 = -0.49999999999999967 - 0.866025403784438i\\
\lambda_4 = -1.3877787807814457 \cdot 10^{-17} + 0.33816678863999095i\\
\lambda_5 = -1.3877787807814457 \cdot 10^{-17} - 0.33816678863999095i\\
\lambda_6 = -0.6036197287523702 + 0i\\
\lambda_7 = 0.6036197287523702 + 0i\\
\lambda_8 = -0.5 + 0i\\
\lambda_9 = 0.5 + 0i
$

So the absolute value of $(-0.49999999999999967 + 0.866025403784438i)$ is $0.9999978$, therefore I would consider this as $\lambda_2$ with $\lambda_1 = 1$. So convergence rate would be $\frac{0.9999978}{1} = 0.9999978$.
If I try to solve this with my implementation of the `Power Method` it does not convergence (only like 4 or 5 steps).

Am I right with my calcuation of the convergence rate?

Comment: There are numerical errors here (note: the imaginary part is only to 4 d.p., so why calculate the magnitude to 7 d.p.?).  The eigenvalues are actually $\frac12(-1\pm\sqrt{-3})$, as there is a deterministic period 3 orbit $3\to 4\to 8\to 3$.

Comment: I updated my post and added all eigenvalues with all digits (which `numpy` computes for me). I can't really follow with `deterministic period 3 oribt`. How did you get to $\frac{1}{2}(-1 +/- \sqrt{-3})$?

Comment: Your $M$ (or rather, should be $M^T$ in the usual Markov chain setup) is the transition probabilities of a Markov chain.  A deterministic period-$n$ orbit tells you if you assign mass $\zeta^j$ on the $j$-th point of the orbit (and $0$ outside the orbit), then the effect of the transition matrix is to multiply by $\zeta$ ($\zeta^n=1$), i.e., you have the eigenvalue $\zeta$ and the corresponding eigenvector of your matrix.

Comment: So you are basically telling me, the eigenvalues calculated by `numpy.eig` are wrong because instead they are multiples of $\frac{1}{2}(-1 +/- \sqrt{-3})$?

Comment: Floating point computations always carry some numerical noise/inaccuracies.  It is never going to give you exact analytical results.

Comment: Does my argumentation still hold truth despite the (small) floating point errors?

Comment: @binaryBigInt It does not hold because the matrix does not have a dominant eigenvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, that matrix does not have a dominant eigenvalue. You have that $|\lambda_1| = |\lambda_2|=|\lambda_3| =1$ and so there is no reason why the method should converge, unless you take as initial approximation an eigenvector associated with $\lambda_1$. The exact values for $\lambda_2, \lambda_3$ are $-\frac 12 \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: What does the last statement here mean? Do those values approximate to a magnitude of 1?